# Symfony login with database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Iam trying to get all data stored in database.

This is my log when i try to submit form.

```
[2018-05-13 02:43:57] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT u0_.id AS id_0, u0_.username AS username_1, u0_.password AS password_2, u0_.roles AS roles_3, u0_.nickname AS nickname_4, u0_.last_access AS last_access_5 FROM user u0_ WHERE u0_.username = ? ["admin@hime.org"] []
[2018-05-13 02:43:57] security.INFO: Authentication request failed. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationServiceException(code: 0): Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 4 bytes at /home/panthera/Repository/Private/PHP/Hime2/vendor/symfony/security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php:85, ErrorException(code: 0): Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 4 bytes at /home/panthera/Repository/Private/PHP/Hime2/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/ArrayType.php:62)"} []
```

My form has 2 fields - email and password, but in database i store much more. 
**id**(int),
**username**(string),
**password**(string),
**role**(array),
**nickname**(string),
**last_access**(DateTime)

I am not sure if this problem is caused by array type, but when i exclude him, problem is gone. But I would really appreciate if i could use him.

as Entity I use automatic created by *make:entity*
I loading data by this method

```
public function loadUserByUsername($username):User
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('user')
        ->andWhere('user.username = :username')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

I've tried to debug code, but when I place var_dump before return, nothing happens. But otherwise when i use "die" it works.. maybe $username is null ?

I am really lost. Thanks for any advice..

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array")
 */
private $roles;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $nickname;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $last_access;

public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

public function getRoles(): ?array
{
    return $this->roles;
}

public function setRoles(array $roles): self
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

public function getNickname(): ?string
{
    return $this->nickname;
}

public function setNickname(?string $nickname): self
{
    $this->nickname = $nickname;

    return $this;
}

public function getLastAccess(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->last_access;
}

public function setLastAccess(?\DateTimeInterface $last_access): self
{
    $this->last_access = $last_access;

    return $this;
}

public function getSalt()
{
    // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    return null;
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
    // TODO: Implement eraseCredentials() method.
    return null;
}
```

}

No answer? :(

EDIT:

Well, I change that, because Symfony creates something and then it cant be used without more code, which is unnecessarily complicated. So I used string which is split by ";" and then i will filter that. Its easier :)

Comment: `var_dump($username);die;` what is the output of the var_dump ? You query seem to be fine. Do your User entity implement the `symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface` ?

Comment: Avoid alias that could be mistaken for entity names. Replace `createQueryBuilder('user')`  with `createQueryBuilder('u')`, and propagate within the whole query. Where did you place this function? Can you add your entity to your question please? Reading the error, it's indeed the array type, you did something wrong with it.

Comment: No, my Entity doesnt implenet UserInterface. As I said i generated it by doctrine make:entity. So i should implement? @Mcsky

Comment: Thanks, i have allready change that. This functioon is in UserRepository.

Comment: When i try to var_dump my parametr to loadUserByUsername, Its normally returns username which i wrote into login form

Comment: please link your entity `User`

Comment: @Mcsky I did and I've also allready updated my class by your previus advice.

Answer (score 0):

What is the column type for `roles`? Unserialization errors are often caused by invalid string conversions. `blob` storage is best for serialized arrays as per docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: When you write down "php bin/console make:entity" it creates these (i selected that, because I want Users to be able own permissions from more roles at 1 time. So I selected Array option

Comment: Yeah - it's the correct internal value for the property/class - but the actual database column that the data is stored in should be a blob if it isn't.

Comment: Well, I allready lost my patient with these. So I removed that Array type and i will use difference solution. - see edit